# Manejar errores 500 con un interceptor, Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

**Necesito** controlar errores 500 del servidor, que **NO** MANEJE en otro lado:

Es decir, yo en ciertas partes de la aplicacion, manejo manualmente los errores 500 de ciertas request, pero para todas las demas, necesito que el interceptor se encargue de manejarlas y mande a una pagina /error:

**MI INTERCEPTOR**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpErrorResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError,EMPTY  } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ErrorsService } from '../services/helpers/errors-server.service';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router:Router,private errorService:ErrorsService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    this.errorService.inProgress.next(false)
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if(error.status.toString().charAt(0) == '5'){
            this.router.navigateByUrl('error')
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Pense, en hacer un servicio y suscribirme en el interceptor, para saber si es un error que no manejo en otro lado. Es decir, cuando manejo un error 500 ya en alguna parte, "activaria" este servicio y cuando el interceptor pregunte, le va a decir que si esta trabajado y no haria nada, mas o menos de la siguiente forma:

```js
 if(error.status.toString().charAt(0) == '5'){
           // Este observable me dice si es un error 500 que YO no valido en ningun lado
          this.errorService.inProgress.subscribe(observer => {
            if(!observer){
              this.router.navigateByUrl('error')
              return EMPTY
            }

            // si es un error 500 pero ya lo trabajo en otro lado no hago nada
            return next.handle(request);
          })
        }
```

El problema de esto, que cuando es un error 500 NO manejado, no cancela el resto y por ende, ese suscriptor puede volver a ser true y nunca hizo nada digamos. Ya que el return EMPTY,no para las request en curso ni nada.

**Repito la necesidad:** Detectar errore 500, **que No este trabajando ya en otra parte de la aplicacion**, y mandarlos a la pagina de error.

Que otra manera se les ocurre?